# Member variable is reachable from outside but its declaring class is garbage-collected in Java?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I'm confused about java member variable and its declaring class in reachable-respect.
Let's say,

1. TestP class has TestC type member variable c1.
2. main class has reference to TestP p and also another reference to p.c1; (`makeP()`)
3. but after p1 reference is removed(`clearP()`),

p1 is garbage-collected even p1.c1 is reachable.

Intesting thing is, if c1 overrides some methods(or even just open&close brackets)
p1 is not garbage-collected. I guess it is because c1 uses some TestP area...
but some clear explanation will be appreciated.

```
public class Main {
    TestP p;
    TestC c;
    void makeP { p = new TestP(); c = p.c1; }
    void clearP { p = null; }
}

public class TestP {
    public TestC c1;

    public TestP() {
        c1 = new TestC(); // TestP will be garbage-collected.
        // c1 = new TestC() {}; // TestP will not be garbage-collected.
    }
    ...
}

public class TestC {
    public TestC() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance of `TestP` can be garbage collected only if there are no references to it. An instance of an anonymous inner class  -- or any inner class -- has a hidden member that is a reference to its enclosing instance; i.e., the object created with

```
c1 = new TestC() {};
```

contains a reference to the `TestP` object in whose constructor this statement was executed. In other words, `c1` points to an instance of a class that actually looks something like this:

```
class TestP$1 extends Test {
    private TestP $outer;

    TestP$1(TestP outer) {
        this.$outer = $outer;
    }
}
```

The constructor argument and member variable are hidden by the compiler, but they're there.

Under those circumstances, the instance of an anonymous subclass of `Test` will prevent the instance of `TestP` from being collected.

Comment: I didn't know about that inner class has hidden reference. It's clear now. Thank you for quick answer.